# tvOS: overlaySKScene in Scenekit's scene prevents touch events on apple tv

Tags: objective-c, scenekit, tvos

I have an overlaySKScene in my scenekit'scene that contains 2 UIButtons. the button opens a table view controller that gives the option navigate to new place in the scene.  it seems having focusable objects as overlay blocks the touch events to the scene. is there a way to over come this issue?

Comment: Hi @Hashmat, did you ever solved this?   I have the same issue, only on iPhone 6s,   on iPad same code works fine.

Comment: i had to find that project and revisit what i had done. those buttons are still uibutton, but are disabled for tvOS. i used siri play button like image for it. so it is just there for visual information. and the real function was redesigned so that siri play button has to handle the action.

Answer (score 0):

Set the "userInteractionEnabled" property of the SKScene to NO.

Comment: thanks, but that won't help because i have a menu uibutton in skscene. that button shows other view. so disabling the the button will solve the problem, but there will be no menu for user. so i have to rethink the whole thing.